# How to invert and tweak the Android sensors like gyroscope, accelerometer, etc.?

Tags: sensors, gyroscope

I am experimenting some VR stuff and I need to know how to invert the gyro sensor and other sensors like accelerometer. Is there any kind of app that can do this? I would like to find an app that can invert the gyroscope so when you turn the phone left with a VR thing, it will turn the opposite direction. Also need to invert the sensor so it displays the information inverted or some sort of program to tweak it without rooting.

Comment: By "accelerometer", do you meaning spoofing GPS & its speed?